# Mail sheets to address in cell A1 - keeping format

Tags: excel, vba

Please can someone advise me on this issue.  I have the below code from Ron de Bruin site to send multiple sheets to email addresses in cell A1.

However when the email is received it has changed the format of the times on the sheets i.e 16:00:00 changed to 0.666666667
 can anyone see how it can be adapted to keep the 16:00:00?

```
 Option Explicit


Sub Mail_Every_Worksheet()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & ""

If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
'You use Excel 97-2003
FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
Else
'You use Excel 2007-2016
FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
End If

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

If sh.Range("A1").Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

sh.Copy

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'Change all cells in the worksheet to values

With wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
.Cells.Copy
.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

TempFileName = "Sheet " & sh.Name & " of " _
& ThisWorkbook.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With wb
.SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
.To = sh.Range("A1").Value
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "TEST"
.Body = "Hi there"
.Attachments.Add wb.FullName
'You can add other files also like this
'.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
.Send 'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

.Close savechanges:=False
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing

Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

End If

Next sh

Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the 0.666666667 located? (Range)

Comment: Hello They are located in column b, from row 6 down

Comment: Sounds like `Range.NumberFormat` may need to be updated to your custom time format `h:mm:ss`. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4 has a thorough explanation of number formatting codes.

Answer (score 0):

I got nerd sniped by your question and refactored your code.

```
Public Sub Mail_Every_Worksheet()
    'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim emailAddress As String
        emailAddress = sh.Range("A1").Value2
        If IsValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) Then
            Dim tempFileName As String
            tempFileName = "Sheet " & sh.Name & " of " & ThisWorkbook.Name & " " & Format$(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
            Dim tempBook As Workbook
            Set tempBook = CreateTempWorkbookFrom(sh, Environ$("temp"), tempFileName)
            Dim tempBookFullPath As String
            tempBookFullPath = tempBook.FullName
            tempBook.Close

            SendOutlookEmailTo emailAddress, vbNullString, vbNullString, "Subject", "Body", tempBookFullPath

            Kill tempBookFullPath
        End If
    Next

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Function IsValidEmailAddress(ByVal value As String) As Boolean
    IsValidEmailAddress = (value Like "?*@?*.?*")
End Function

Private Function CreateTempWorkbookFrom(ByVal copySheet As Worksheet, ByVal tempSavePath As String, ByVal tempFileName As String) As Workbook
    If Right$(tempSavePath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        tempSavePath = tempSavePath & Application.PathSeparator
    End If

    copySheet.Copy
    Set CreateTempWorkbookFrom = ActiveWorkbook

    With CreateTempWorkbookFrom.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
        'Change all cells in the worksheet to values
        .Cells.Value2 = .Cells.Value2
    End With

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        CreateTempWorkbookFrom.SaveAs tempSavePath & tempFileName & ".xls", xlWorkbookNormal
    Else
        CreateTempWorkbookFrom.SaveAs tempSavePath & tempFileName & ".xlsm", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    End If
End Function

Private Sub SendOutlookEmailTo(ByVal emailAddress As String, _
                                ByVal CC As String, _
                                ByVal BCC As String, _
                                ByVal Subject As String, _
                                ByVal Body As String, _
                                ParamArray attachments() As Variant)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim mailItem As Object 'Outlook.mailItem 'Tools>References>Microsoft Outlook X.xx Object Library
    Const OutlookMailItem As Long = 0
    Set mailItem = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(OutlookMailItem) ' Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With mailItem
        .To = emailAddress
        .CC = CC
        .BCC = BCC
        .Subject = Subject
        .Body = Body

        Dim attachment As Variant
        For Each attachment In attachments
            .attachments.Add attachment
        Next

        .Display

        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you ivenbach I really appreciate your help

Comment: Hello,I am getting an error at the below line in the code .Cells.Value2 = .Cells.Value2 @IvenBach

Comment: What is the error saying? That line is essentially copying the cells as values and makes any formulas into their evaluated results. Try altering it to be a `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial` on their own lines.

Comment: Hello,I have changed it as advised but the email is now coming through with the time in the wrong format (as below)                             LOADING TIME Reference1
0.541666667 77467
0.625 77468
0.666666667 77469

Comment: I cant seem to get it to copy and paste exactly as it looks originally.  Is it possible to make it convert to PDF instead?

Comment: `copySheet.Copy` will copy the sheet as it is. regarding PDF conversion https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel the `Workbook.SaveAs` method will be what you need to look at to achieve that result.